# Why do I have to set the number 1 in the clauses of each case, not 2?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What if I did not set 1, but 2 or 3? The different total number came out. Would you mind telling me what the result number is?
I have been trying a new challenge assigned by my class. I created three columns in a single table by using conditional clause, CASE. However, I do not know why I have to set 1, but not 2 or 3 in the conditional clauses. I did 2, but the result was different. It showed the number over around 300.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE rating
    WHEN 'R' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS r,
SUM(CASE rating
    WHEN 'PG' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS pg,
SUM(CASE rating
    WHEN 'PG-13' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS pg13
FROM film;
```

RIGHT ANSWER
r:195
pg:194
pg13:223

I really want to be able to imagine the process of the calculation of the number if I set 2 in the clauses.

Comment: For each R, you add 1 to the sum. I.e. you count the R's. If you instead add 2, you will get twice the actual number of R's.

Comment: If you remove the aggregation, you'll see what different numbers do, and why you get different results when you sum those values

Comment: @jarlh If i did set "2", what number is going to be added or accumulated?

Comment: @HoneyBadger If i did set "2", what number is going to be added or accumulated?

Comment: Why imagine? ... just change the value to see what happens. Surely, using 2 or 3 as the value for a running total will only double or triple the amount. Are you not getting the correct totals using 1?

Comment: @PaulT. Hi Paul
I know I do not need to think of it since the code works properly. Since I want to make sure I grasp everything concisely, this is why I think that, which I could do that I did not care about it. I understood the number one, but using 2 or 3 still needs having some crystal clear, haha .